# Comparing explicit generators of the $n$-th singular homology group of $S^n$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $\Delta^n$ be the standard $n$-simplex, $S^n$ the unit $n$-sphere, $D^n$ the closed unit $n$-ball. Consider the following two generators of $H_n(S^n)$ (the $n$-th singular homology group of $S^n$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients):

1. Let $\Delta_1,\Delta_2:\Delta^n\to S^n$ be embeddings of $\Delta^n$ into $S^n$ as the upper and lower hemispheres. Then $\Delta_1-\Delta_2$ is a generator of $H_n(S^n)$ as is shown in Hatcher's text.
2. The boundary (in the singular chain complex) of the identity map $\operatorname{id}_{\Delta^{n+1}}$ determines a homology class in $H_n(\partial\Delta^{n+1})$. Under a homeomorphism $\partial\Delta^{n+1}\cong S^n$, this determines a homology class in $H_n(S^n)$.

> Question: Are these two homology classes equal? More precisely, since it depends on the identifications of $\Delta^n$ with the hemispheres and $\partial\Delta^{n+1}\cong S^n$, the appropriate question would be: How does one choose identifications consistently so that they determine the same generator for all $n$?

This question arises when one considers the boundary operator in cellular homology, where the first generator is chosen for the domain and the second for the target. Hatcher seems to be quite careless about sign problems, so I tried to do it myself. But these really come from two different simplicial decompositions of $S^n$ and (I think) it would be quite messy to compare them directly, even in dimension $2$. Are there any better ways to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you have to do is to write down *one* formula for a homeomorphism $\Delta_1$ from $\Delta^n$ to the upper hemisphere of $S^n$, *one* formula $\Delta_2$ for a homeomorphism from $\Delta^n$ to the lower hemisphere of $S^n$, and *one* formula for a homeomorphism $\partial\Delta^{n+1} \approx S^n$. They must be appropriate formulas, of course, and then you must use them to prove everything that must be proved. Yes, formulas for functions can be messy, but that doesn't remove the necessity of writing down an appropriate formula. Have you tried to do that?

Comment: @LeeMosher The problem is that it doesn't help to write down explicit formulae of homeomorphisms. For example, for the $S^2$ case one can draw explicit pictures. However, I don't know how to compare them other than first subdividing the simplicial structures so that they are represented by cycles in the same simplicial chain complex. But even if it solves the problem for $S^2$, doesn't it get extremely cumbersome for general $n$?

Comment: Well, let me propose a question. What's written in 1 is false because it depends very much upon *which* two homeomorphisms you pick (one to the upper hemisphere, one to the lower hemisphere): if you pick those two homeomorphisms wrongly then $\Delta_1 - \Delta_2$ is not even a cycle. If you pick them correctly, however, then one can prove very easily that $\Delta_1 - \Delta_2$ is a cycle *and* that its homology class is a generator. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, that was a minor mistake. What I had in mind was actually a homeomorphism between $S^n$ and the space obtained by gluing two copies of the standard $n$-simplex along the boundary. Still I don't see how writing down an explicit homeomorphism helps. For example, for (1), project the standard $\Delta^n\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ to the first $n$-coordinates to get $\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n):0\leq x_1+\ldots+x_n\leq1,x_i\geq0\}$. This is homeomorphic to $D^n$ (since it is star-shaped; one can in fact write an explicit but ugly formula here, obtained by stretching it radially),

Comment: (continued) then take the homeomorphisms of $D^n$ to the hemispheres by $x\mapsto(x,\pm\sqrt{1-|x|^2})$. The formula is necessarily complicated.